# How to use .emit() and .on() methods in browsers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, browser

I'm writing a game in browser and I'm trying to find how to use `.emit()` and `.on()` methods in browsers. I can't get it to work as I get an error that `.emit()` is undefined. Can anyone explain how to get it working?

For example, I'm trying to implement the following API for my game:

```
var game = new Game();

game.on('start', function(){
  draw_players();
});
game.on('end', function(){
  display_end_game_message();
});
etc.
```

And inside Game function I've something like this that emits `start`:

```
function Game(){
  function connect(){
    emit('start');
  }
}
```

How do I get `emit()` and `on()` working in browser?

Comment: You know that `emit()` and `on()` are Node.js specific `EventEmitter` methods, right??

Comment: @thefourtheye Yes, but aren't browsers Node.js?

Comment: of course is NOT defined there's no such Game object or emit method built-in to javascript...are you using `node.js` by any chance?

Comment: @bodacydo No, Node.js is used for running Javascript on the server.

Comment: oh dear...mate, a good piece of advice...read a `node.js` tutorial first

Comment: @bodacydo Chrome Browser and Node.js share the V8 JavaScript execution engine. Apart from that, Node.js is used to execute JavaScript in the Server side, and Chrome does the same in the Client side. But they have different capabilities. For example, Node.js has Streams and stuff, where as Chrome has DOM and stuff

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood. I thought browsers used node.js. What I really would like to do is somehow use these programming paradigms that node.js has in the browser. Is there a js library that provides `emit` and `on` like in Node.js?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to `<script src="emit_and_on.js"></script>` and then use them for my Game object. :)

Comment: @Leo I'm writing Game object myself (in game.js). I'm just trying to figure out how to use events with my Game in the browser. :) (I a little bit misunderstood difference between browser JS environmenta nd node.js.) Sorry!

Comment: @bodacydo I have never done that before, you might have to search and find a library yourself. Sorry :(

Comment: Here's an `EventEmitter` object like the one used by node.js: https://github.com/Wolfy87/EventEmitter that you can use in the browser if you want.  You will probably want your game object to inherit from it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `emit` and `on` are node-specific functions that come with node libraries and only work when running your javascript server-side via Node.js

If you want to write your game using node, you should try out [Browserify](http://superbigtree.tumblr.com/post/54873453939/introduction-to-browserify) that will convert your node.js scripts to run on a browser.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `emit` and `on`, you can use the events that are in the browser [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

They work similarly. Only they have `addEventListener` instead of `on`, and `dispatchEvent` instead of `emit`

And for their work, you will need to create some kind of DOM-element

here is an example for your implementation

```
const gameEl = document.createElement('div')
const gameStartEvent = new Event('game-start')

gameEl.addEventListener('game-start', () => {
    draw_players();
})

function Game(){
    function connect(){
        gameEl.dispatchEvent(gameStartEvent);
    }
}
```